# Why are the #include and #includedir directives in sudo prefixed with the pound (#) character

Tags: sudo

While setting up a `sudo` environment I noticed that the include directive is prefixed with the pound (#) character.

Solaris shows this as:

```
## Read drop-in files from /etc/sudoers.d
## (the '#' here does not indicate a comment)
#includedir /etc/sudoers.d
```

The manual (Linux as well as Solaris) states:

> Including other files from within sudoers
>        It is possible to include other sudoers files from within
>        the sudoers file currently being parsed using the #include
>        and #includedir directives.

And:

> Other special characters and reserved words
>        The pound sign (`#') is used to indicate a comment (unless
>        it is part of a #include directive or unless it occurs in
>        the context of a user name and is followed by one or more
>        digits, in which case it is treated as a uid).  Both the
>        comment character and any text after it, up to the end of
>        the line, are ignored.

Does anybody knows why the choice was made to use the pound character in the `#include` and `#includedir` directives?

As a side note: I often use something like `egrep -v '^#|^$' configfile` to get the non-default/active configured settings, and this obviously does not work for the `sudoers` file.

Comment: Also known as an Octothorpe.

Comment: I once regard `#includedir /etc/sudoers.d`  as a comment and remove it, making me nearly can't use "sudo" command.  Similar things: modeline for vim. Any relationship among them?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

`#include` was added [in 2004](https://www.sudo.ws/repos/sudo/rev/a78015ca81af). It had to be compatible with what was already there. I don't think `include /path/to/file` would have been ambiguous, though, but it might have been a little harder to parse, because the parser would have to distinguish `include /path/to/file` (include directive) from `include = foo` (allow the user `include` to run the command `foo`).

But I think mostly the reason was to look like the C preprocessor, which the [manual](https://www.sudo.ws/repos/sudo/rev/fbb92a25a726) explicitly cites as inspiration.

Comment: Nice catch and explanation, unfortunately those explanations are removed from the manuals (at least on Ubuntu, RedHat, OpenBSD and Solaris).

Comment: The first time I analyzed my `sudoers` file I thought `include` is a directive and `#include` is a directive *commented out*. The rule of least surprise violated hard. In my opinion it's bad design.

Comment: The comment should read "the # here does not mean a comment. *Sorry.*"

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski It's not bad. It's disastrous! I tried removing the hash tag before includedir, and I suddenly can't sudo any more. I was on an Ubuntu server, and had no other means to acquire root privilege. The result is a full reinstall (fortunately the broken OS was just a fresh install)

Comment: Ridiculous to use a hash (e.g. comment), regardless of the reason.

Answer (score 12):

> As a side note: I often use something like egrep -v '^#|^$' configfile to get the non-default/active configured settings, and this obviously does not work for the sudoers file.

This will work from [sudo version 1.9.1](https://github.com/sudo-project/sudo/releases/tag/SUDO_1_9_1) as support for `@include` and `@includedir` has been added to make it ["less confusing"](https://github.com/sudo-project/sudo/commit/741c6f274e65f852b7026b10a21dff519b2fd6c2).

> **Add support for @include and @includedir**
>
> These are less confusing than #include and #includedir when the
> hash character is also the comment character.
>
> This commit also adds real parsing of include directives as opposed
> to the pure lexer approach used previously.  As a result, it is now
> possible to include files with spaces by either using a double-quoted
> string or escaping the space characters with a backslash.

Use of `#include` and `#includedir` is [retained](https://github.com/sudo-project/sudo/blob/SUDO_1_9_1/doc/sudoers.mdoc.in#L1755) for compatibility with versions prior to 1.9.1.

Comment: "less confusing" shouldn't be in quotes. It _is_ confusing! :)

Comment: It makes good sense for "less confusing" to be in quotes, because that is directly-quoted text.